# AccessViolationException on Control.Invoke

Tags: c#, access-violation

My setup is as follows. I have a UI Thread with a Log property which updates a RichTextBox. I have a non-UI Thread That populates the Log property. The non-UI Thread is controlled by a Timer. I also have a Button that in the UI that updates the Log property. The LogPresenter is just a class that formats the message and sends it to the Log Property.

I am receiving, randomly, an AccessViolationException when I update the SelectedText property on the RichTextBox. Here the pertaining code

```
public static class ThreadHelpers
{
    public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control c, Action a)
    {
        if (c.InvokeRequired)
            c.Invoke(a);
        else
            a();
    }
}

public string Log
{
    set
    {
        lock (value)
        {
            richLog.InvokeIfRequired(() => OnLogMessage(value));
        }                
    }
}

[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
private void OnLogMessage(string message)
{
    try
    {
        richLog.SelectionStart = richLog.Text.Length;

        var selection = message.Split('-');
        var loggingLevel = selection[0].Trim();

        switch (loggingLevel)
        {
            case "Information":
                richLog.SelectionColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                break;
            case "Warning":
                richLog.SelectionColor = Color.Goldenrod;
                break;
            case "Error":
                richLog.SelectionColor = Color.DarkRed;
                break;
            case "SuccessAudit":
                richLog.SelectionColor = Color.DarkOliveGreen;
                break;
            case "FailureAudit":
                richLog.SelectionColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                break;
            default:
                richLog.SelectionColor = Color.Silver;
                break;
        }

        richLog.SelectedText = message;
        ScrollToBottom();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        // The lines below just cause cascading fail so I took them out.
        //_logPresenter.Fail("Failed to write Log: {0}", message);
        //_logPresenter.Error("{0}" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace: {0}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
     }
 }
```

The Exact Error I am getting is this:
System.AccessViolationException

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, EDITSTREAM lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.StreamIn(Stream data, Int32 flags)
   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.StreamIn(String str, Int32 flags)
   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.set_SelectedText(String value)
   at Namespace.InteractiveServiceForm.OnLogMessage(String message) in c:\projects\Namespace\InteractiveServiceForm.cs:line 127
```

I tried the lock but it is not helping any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Also the app is now just hanging the UI.

Comment: Add `Debug.Assert(c.IsHandleCreated)` as the first line to `InvokeIfRequired`

Comment: Okay, I've added Debug.Assert in. I'm waiting for the app to hit the problem again. The message box does pop when I start the application. I'll get back to you after it crashes again.

Comment: You are making promises you can't keep.  Can you *really* handle "corrupted state" exceptions?  If you did then you wouldn't be asking this question.  Can you *really* catch every exception and handle them?  Stop fibbing and you'll have a shot at debugging this.  A minidump can tell you where it fell over, it isn't in managed code.

Comment: @HansPassant that's not the most constructive comment. I have looked all over the internet and I am continuing to look. I am not sure where I am lying. The only spot I can think that you would think I am is when I say I will get back with Zer0 after it crashes again. But it will crash again I just don't know when. I assume that Zer0 had me include the Debug.Assert because he/she wants to know if the reason I am getting the error is because the handle is lost. If you are not going to help then don't respond.

Comment: @Zer0 I just hit the error again and it did not run into the Debug.Assert statement.

Comment: Well, that didn't take that long.  I explained how you can debug this.  If you think that's an unconstructive way to go about it then good luck with it, you'll need it.  AVEs in operating system code is as nasty as they come.